# No error while trying to delete row with a keyvalue

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i want to delete rows in a dataframe with a key-value. I have the code but it wont work. I dont get an error or something else. It simply dont delete the rows. I tried different things but nothing helped. May you can give me an answer.

Here is the List:

```
       FAK_ART    FAK_DAT  LEIST_DAT      KD_CRM MW_BW       EQ_NR MATERIAL  \
```

From this list i want to delete in the column MW_BW the rows with the keyvalue 'P'.

Thats my code for that:

```
data_faktura[data_faktura.MW_BW != 'P']
```

For explanation: data_faktura is my dataframe.

What im doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you doing it like this - ```data_fakura = data_faktura[data_faktura.MW_BW != 'P']```? You have to assign the returned df back to the original df.

Comment: How can make this?

Comment: Replace your line of code with - ```data_faktura = data_faktura[data_faktura.MW_BW != 'P']```.

Comment: oh man ... thanks! Thats it!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your value `P` has some spaces before or after letter:

So try [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) whitespaces:

```
data_faktura[data_faktura.MW_BW.str.strip() != 'P']
```

Sample:

```
data_faktura = pd.DataFrame({'MW_BW':[' P','E','P'],
                             'B':[4,5,6]})

print (data_faktura)
   B MW_BW
0  4     P
1  5     E
2  6     P

print (data_faktura[data_faktura.MW_BW != 'P'])
   B MW_BW
0  4     P
1  5     E

print (data_faktura[data_faktura.MW_BW.str.strip() != 'P'])
   B MW_BW
1  5     E
```

EDIT:

You can also generate list of values, which are not omited:

```
print (df)
   FAK_ART     FAK_DAT   LEIST_DAT KD_CRM MW_BW       EQ_NR MATERIAL
0     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100107  S
1     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100107  S
2     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100108  S
3     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100108  S
4     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100109  S
5     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     P  100109  S
6     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100110  S
7     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100110  S
8     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100111  S
9     ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100111  S
10    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100112  S
11    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100112  S
12    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100113  S
13    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     P  100113  S
14    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     E  100114  S
15    ZPAF  2015-05-18  2015-05-31    D     B  100114  S

print (df.ix[[5,13],'MW_BW'].tolist())
['P', 'P']
```

Comment: Yes, please see edit - try generate list with indexes where are values `P`, whih are not excluded.

Comment: im sorry but i dont understand your edit! Can you explain it?

Comment: Sorry, only you can generate problematic `P` values, which are not excluded and check it, if there is some problem.

Comment: the point is i get the data with E, P and B as Value for MW_BW-column. I cant edit it. I tried now to delete E or B and it didnt worked as well. Thats strange and i dont have any idea why. Is it important that i create the dataframe from a excel-file? Is that maybe the reason for that?

Comment: What return `print (df.ix[[5,13],'MW_BW'].tolist())` ? It looks like good?

Comment: Can you share your file?

Comment: TrigonaMinima fixed it! Thanks jezrael! ;)

Comment: Super, i think there was some complicated problem.